# PWA appearing black when using blob

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I'm making an offline PWA installer using Blob, but when I share and add to home screen on IOS, the PWA appears completely black. Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function install(){
   var autodate, enapp, data;

   // Getting current PWA
   $("#autodate").load("https://mysite.github.io/pwa/app1.html");
   autodate = document.getElementById('autodate');

    setTimeout(() => {
        // Encode
        encapp = btoa(autodate.innerHTML);

        // Blob
        blobt('text/html', 'data:text/html;base64,'+encapp)
    }, 300);
};

function blobt(type, data){
    const base64data = data;
    const contentType = type;

    const byteCharacters = atob(base64data.substr(`data:${contentType};base64,`.length));
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += 1024) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + 1024);

        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(blobUrl, '_blank');
}
</script>
```

I don't see what would make it not work. It does everything perfectly in-browser, but once you install it to home screen, it just blacks out. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your `manifest.json`. But my guess is that the app won't allow you to use `window.open` to open a new tab because that wouldn't be very *Web App* kind of behavior. Could you include your manifest? And would you care to elaborate why you chose this approach?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier the `window.open` works. and I don't have a manifest.

Comment: Well, if you've got an OSX device, then you could use the XCode Simulator to fire up a virtual instance of OSX. Then you could use Safari devtools to inspect the browser on the virtual device. Anyway, is there a way for us to run your code so we can experience your issue for our selfs? Because right now, there is very little to go on.